# Drag event not firing

Tags: javascript, drag

The drag event is not firing.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

items.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("drag", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(item);
    item.classList.add("dragging");
  });
});
```

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item.dragging {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I wanted it to set a class on being dragged but it didn;t even fire. I also added a `preventDefault()` method but that didn't work either.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your question to contain a runnable snippet but had to improvise the CSS. If it differs greatly to your actual code, please [edit] the question

Comment: You seem to be missing the `draggable` attribute on your elements. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API#identify_what_is_draggable

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem. @Phil